# Javascript programme to restict zoom on google map

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am going to include a google map to my web application and I will use markers. The map works perfectly, the problem is that I want to restrict zoom level for polygons like square, star, triangle and not for circle,pindrop. I don´t know how to do it in javascript, can anybody help?

This is the script I use:

```
 `<script type="text/javascript">
  success: function (data)

{
   {

        var markers = data;
        if (markers.length == 0)
        {
            var mapProp =
                {

                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.318598, 47.954674),
                   zoom: gZoom, 
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
               };
       }


        else {
            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),


              zoom: gZoom, 
                maxZoom: 17,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID 
            };
        }


      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
        var _gmap = {};
        if (gMap == null)
       {
            gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);


       } 
       else 
        {

           for (var i = 0; i < markersPoint.length; i++) 
            {
              markersPoint[i].setMap(null);  
            }

           gMap.setOptions('center', new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng)); 
       } 

        gZoom = gMap.getZoom();
      mZoom = gMap.setZoom(17); 
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 

       markersPoint = []; 
       for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
        {
            var marker;
            var CurrData = markers[i]
            var colour = CurrData.Colour;
            if (colour == "NULL")
                colour = "#000000";
            var CurrLatlong = new google.maps.LatLng(CurrData.lat, CurrData.lng);

            var pathShape = GetCordShape(CurrData.lat, CurrData.lng, CurrData.Shape);

            var pinSVGFilled = "M 12,2 C 8.1340068,2 5,5.1340068 5,9 c 0,5.25 7,13 7,13 0,0 7,-7.75 7,-13 0,-3.8659932 -3.134007,-7 -7,-7 z";
            _path = google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE;

            if (CurrData.Shape == "Circle" || CurrData.Shape == "Pindrop")

            {
                if (CurrData.Shape == "Pindrop")
                {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: CurrLatlong,
                        map: gMap,
                        title: CurrData.Bhname,
                        icon: {
                            path: pinSVGFilled,
                            scale: 1,
                            fillColor: colour,
                            fillOpacity: 0.8,
                            strokeWeight: 0.9
                        }
                    });
                }

                else {

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: CurrLatlong,
                        map: gMap,
                        title: CurrData.Bhname,
                        icon: {
                            path: _path,
                            scale: 5,
                            fillColor: colour,
                            fillOpacity: 0.8,
                            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                            strokeWeight: 0.9
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

            else {
                marker = new google.maps.Polygon
                    ({
                        map: gMap,
                        paths: pathShape,
                        scale: 5,
                        strokeOpacity: 0.3,
                        title: CurrData.Bhname,
                        strokeWeight: 1,
                        fillColor: colour,
                        fillOpacity: 0.8,
                        radius: 10,
                        position: CurrLatlong,
                        hover: CurrData.Bhname

                    });
            }


            bounds.extend(CurrLatlong);
            markersPoint.push(marker);
```

`

Comment: are you asking that you want to set different zoom levels for a single map at the same time?

Comment: Not for same time,according to the shapes or markers selected on the map.Here we have option for choosing shapes circle and pindrops are default shapes and have no restriction on zooming but star,triangle,square need restrictions for zooming

Comment: Please address your requirement clearly on which event you want to change the zoom level.whether during on click events of the different marker shapes or during zoom in of the whole map . include a working sample jsfiddle if possible for us to understand your issue

Comment: I included both custom and default marker shapes ,when selecting markers as default shapes like circle and pindrop no restrictions for zooming the whole map.When i select custom markers the whole map shows restrictions for zooming.

Comment: i want to set different zooming for differernt markers on goolge map

Answer (score 0):

check this jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/b86usz0e/)

html:

```
    <h1>Map</h1>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

jquery + javascript:

```
    var infowindow = null;
var gmarkers = [];

var defaultIcon = {url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png',
// This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
                   size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
// The origin for this image is 0,0.
                   origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
// The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
                   anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)};

var activeIcon = {url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png',
// This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
                  size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
// The origin for this image is 0,0.
                  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
// The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
                  anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)};

                  // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
// The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
// traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
// coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
// coordinate.
var shape = {
    coord: [9, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 14, 2, 16, 5, 19, 7, 23, 8, 26, 9, 30, 9, 34, 11, 34, 11, 30, 12, 26, 13, 24, 14, 21, 16, 18, 18, 16, 20, 12, 20, 8, 18, 4, 16, 2, 15, 1, 13, 0],
    type: 'poly'
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();
});

function initialize() {

    var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(39.828175, -98.5795);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: centerMap,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    setMarkers(map, sites);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "loading..."
    });

    var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
    bikeLayer.setMap(map);
}

var sites = [
    ['Mount Evans', 39.58108, -105.63535, 4, 'This is Mount Evans.','custom'],
    ['Irving Homestead', 40.315939, -105.440630, 2, 'This is the Irving Homestead.','normal'],
    ['Badlands National Park', 43.785890, -101.90175, 1, 'This is Badlands National Park','normal'],
    ['Flatirons in the Spring', 39.99948, -105.28370, 3, 'These are the Flatirons in the spring.','normal']
];



function setMarkers(map, markers) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var marker1 = "";
        var marker = "";
        console.log(sites);
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        if(sites[3] == 1){
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            icon: defaultIcon,
            zIndex: sites[3],
            html: sites[4],
            class:sites[5]
        });
         var contentString = "Some content";
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                gmarkers[i].setIcon(defaultIcon);  
            }
            this.setIcon(activeIcon);
            map.setZoom(7);
            map.setCenter(marker1.getPosition()); 
        });
        gmarkers.push(marker1);
        }else{

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            icon: defaultIcon,
            zIndex: sites[3],
            html: sites[4],
            class:sites[5]
        });
         var contentString = "Some content";
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                gmarkers[i].setIcon(defaultIcon);  
            }
            this.setIcon(activeIcon);
            map.setZoom(2);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); 
        });
         gmarkers.push(marker);
        }
    }
}
```

css:

```
html,body,#map_canvas{
height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
img[src^='http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png?i=']{
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

This example zooms in upto level 7 for badlands national park, for other places it the zoom level is 2. So click on marker and see the different zoom in levels for different marker.